# blurry display/ white background behind text - brand new pc? NVIDIA

Tags: graphics-card, resolution, hdmi

I just bought a brand new Desktop PC. Everything works fine, but there are **some** display problems...

I'm connecting to my Samsung LED TV that is 1080p. My old computer was plugged in through DVI and everything was working fine, no problems and perfect display resolution and quality, but this new PC isn't really able to work with DVI as I get "no signal" on my TV. So I was like okay, I'll use HDMI. Now I'm using HDMI to HDMI (brand new cable, no possibility of damaged cable). The first thing I noticed was that the screen exceeded the tv's borders even though the resolution was 1920x1080. I fixed it by setting display on my TV from **16:9** to **Fit the screen**. The resolution itself is alright and perfectly fit. The problem is that I'm experiencing kind of a poor quality on my TV. I dont really know why, as my graphic card (GTX 745 4GB) is supporting HDMI and 4k resolution. I tried to do some stuff in control panel of nvidia, but nothing really. I searched the whole internet about this problem I'm having, like zig-zag lines (something like anti aliasing problems or smth like that..) and the display quality itself looks really bad. Another thing is that behind the text, there is a white background-ish stuff that is trying to fill the background of text somehow... Idk what that is. I never had problems like this...

I can't even put screenshots of this problem as the screenshot itself is looking good on another computer, without any graphical errors...

It looks like there is problem with either HDMI settings or nVidia settings...

I don't believe that the HDMI itself would not support this quality...

Additional information: I reinstalled all nvidia drivers to either to older ones as I saw somewhere that the older ones are better in one way, Now I'm currently running on the latest graphic card drivers, but the problems of poor quality display persist.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Facing this problem only in TV?

Comment: I tried it on another big LCD 4k tv and same results...

Comment: I assume that there is no problem with the video card itself, but the output from it